# How to copy selection from one select to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select elements, with same number of options, and same values for these options, but different (translated) texts.

How can I copy selection from one to another?

From user perspective, if someone will select "red" *(value=1)* and "brown" *(value=5)* in English select, I want "rubrum" *(value=1)* and "rufum" *(value=5)* to appear selected in Latin select.

For `<input>` tags, this works:

```
$(this).closest('.common-parent')
.find(".common-identifier")
.not(this)
.val( $(this).val() );
```

Sadly, this omits `<select>` tags.

I found many ways to copy items, but can't find a way to copy actual selection.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/e53aJ/8/

Edit: I'd love it to work both for single and multiselect, if possible. I know at first I did not reflect that in my fiddle, sorry.

Comment: If you could setup a fiddle to get to the issue would be nice

Comment: @Jai you mean http://jsfiddle.net/ ? I'll try.

Comment: @Jai done, fiddle added

Comment: answer updated take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<select>` elements have a property `selectedIndex` that indicates which of their options is selected.

If you get the `selectedIndex` of the one `<select>`, then set the `selectedIndex` of the other `<select>` to that, you should get the result you're looking for.

However, if your `<select>` accepts multiple selections (as your question implies), then it's a bit more tiresome. You have to loop through the `<option>` elements and check each one to see whether it's `selected` property is true.

(This is why jQuery's popular: the JavaScript DOM interface frequently *sucks*.)

Comment: @PaulDWaite you don't happen to know any jQuery shorthand for this? Just regular loop / jQuery each() is what I need?

Comment: @Molot: jQuery shorthand for which bit?

Comment: For looping over elements and setting selected. My code now is scary ;) but works with `.each()` all right, it's just ugly that way.

Comment: @Molot: what’s wrong with `each`? Could you post your code somewhere?

Comment: @Mołot: sorry, you’ve already posted it in the Fiddle haven’t you. It’s a bit tricky because it’s bidirectional. You’ve got one change handler assigned to all of the `<select>`s, but when one changes, it makes the others change, which will probably trigger the same event handler again. Maybe you could re-post your new code in a new question that specifically discusses the part you’re having a problem with. (Otherwise the question is a bit “I’m trying to do this thing, please write my code for me.”)

Comment: OK, I have it working. Loop like you told, with attr and removeAttr, and flags to avoid re-triggering. But it's a bit to ugly to post now. I'll try do ask "how to simplify it" when I'll get the chance to clean up code from project-specific data.

Answer (score 3):

I saw your html markup there you supplied all `option` values to `1` that should be in order like below:

### Html:

```
    <div class=".common-identifier">
        <select name="english" class=".common-identifier">
            <option value=1>red</option>
            <option value=2>green</option>
            <option value=3>yellow</option>
            <option value=4>blue</option>
            <option value=5>brown</option>
        </select>
        <select name="latin" class=".common-identifier">
            <option value=1>rubeum</option>
            <option value=2>viride</option>
            <option value=3>flavus</option>
            <option value=4>caeruleo</option>
            <option value=5>brunneis</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

### jQuery:

```
$('select[name="english"]').on('change', function () {
   $('select[name="latin"]').val(this.value);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e53aJ/6/)

Comment: OK, seems it works. However, fails miserably on multiple: http://jsfiddle.net/e53aJ/8/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('.common-parent')
.find(".common-identifier")
.not(this)
.attr('selectedIndex', $(this).attr('selectedIndex'));
```